# git diff --check missing all white spaces

Tags: git

I am using `git diff --check` to check for any trailing white spaces, but it never highlights any. Please see the image that shows what I am expecting...

I intentionally include white spaces in `Python` and `C#` scripts, but this command still does nothing.

I have checked the documentation for this command, but as far as I can see, I am not doing anything wrong.

I have also run the `git config --global core.whitespace \ trailing-space,space-before-tab,indent-with-non-tab` command to make sure I have not accidentally disabled this feature, but it still does not detect the blank spaces I deliberately put in.

What am I missing?

[image]

(Taken from the pro git ebook)

Comment: Have you checked that you do not have anything line `-trailing-space` in `config.whitespace`?

Comment: @kirelagin Thanks. I checked the git-pro book and found that running `git config --global core.whitespace \ trailing-space,space-before-tab,indent-with-non-tab` will achieve the 3 commonly-desired ones, but it still cannot detect the blank spaces I deliberately put in. Is this what you meant, or have I not understood you right? I could not seem to find `config.whitespace` by the way...

Comment: Yes, that’s what I meant. I just wanted to make sure that you have not accidentally disabled treating trailing whitespace as errors. Running the command was not necessary as the defaults are fine. I’m sorry, I have no other ideas.

Comment: @kirelagin No worries. Thank you very much for trying to help me.

Answer (score 0):

When I read sources like this, I assume the "\" character is to indicate that in the medium you're using to read, the line covers multiple lines; in other words, the line doesn't fit on the page.

I believe you should not be using the "\" in this scenario.

Comment: You are right. I failed to realize that... Thank you. Now, when I run the `git diff --check` command, I get: `warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in test.py.  The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.` Is this how it should be, instead of highlighting where the white spaces are located?

Comment: Weird i remember it specifying the line number